# Importing .json into Typescript as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I am trying to import a .json file into Typescript as an array and do not know how to grab the values.

```
import * as data from './list.json';

  const array = data;
  console.log(array);
```

My json file

```
[
  "Element 1",
  "Element 2",
  "Element 3",
  "Element 4",
  "Element 5"
]
```

This is what the variable array looks like in the console when I am trying to log it in console.
I can see that all elements from the array are there under default: But I do not know how to access that.
I have tried array[0] and that is undefined

```
Module
default: Array(5)
0: "Element 1"
1: "Element 2"
2: "Element 3"
3: "Element 4"
4: "Element 5"
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
__esModule: true
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to import the default export is this syntax

```
import data from './list.json';

const array = data;
console.log(array);
```

But you should also be able to access the array elements with your import method:

```
import * as data from './list.json';

const array = data;
console.log(array[1]); // 'Element 2'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can import json.

```
import json from "file.json";
```

```
import json = require("file.json");
```

```
import * as json from "file.json";
```

You can use whichever you want. The first one is preferred.

Comment: For the first option you need to write "resolveJsonModule": true in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

### If you are importing an array from JSON in TypeScript, and it doesn't import as an array, this answer will help.

I was using:

```
import * as items from 'file.json'; 

console.log(`>>>`, Array.isArray(productDetails));
console.log(`>>>`, Object.keys(productDetails));
```

returns an Object that has numerical keys (like an Array) but that is not an Array:

```
  console.log
    >>> false

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/file.ts:67:9)

  console.log
    >>> [
      '0',  '1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',  '8',  '9',
      '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
      '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29',
      '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39',
      '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49',
      '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59',
      '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69',
      '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79',
      '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89',
      '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99',
      ... 1410 more items
    ]
```

As you can see, the object was importing as an plain Object, not an Array.

Changing the import to:

```
import items from 'file.json';
```

Resolved the issue, importing `items` as an Array.